# Absoluteness of exponential function and forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I recall reading that the exponential function $ \alpha^{\beta}$ is absolute for transitive models of ZFC.

Is it true that if we have  $ 2^{ \alpha } < \beta $ in the ground model $V$, then $( 2^{ \check{ \alpha} } < \check{\beta})^{V[G]} $ holds as well?

Does it make sense to refer to  $ 2^{\check{\alpha}}$ as an ordinal in an extension model statement as I did above?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinal arithmetic is not changed between transitive models. And forcing does not change the ordinals.

So $2^\alpha$ is just the same ordinal as it was before.

Comment: +1. Note for the OP that **cardinal** exponentiation is of course not absolute.

Comment: Of course. Good point.